# Background image URL failed to load in browser but working in local

Tags: css, image, url, load, background-image

I have given like this in style

```
background:#000 url(../img/dot.png) repeat 0 0;
```

Its working well in local drive but when it goes in live background image alone is not loading, in browser it shows "Failed to load the given URL"

Comment: Check Your image Path.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that you have no ad-block software stopping the picture

Comment: Worked for me after hitting a brick wall for an hour!  The filename 'cpd_banner_ads.gif' must have been tripping ad-blocks alarm.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more code would be helpful. Anyhow.

Make sure the path ()../img/dot.ong) to the file is correct.
Is your img folder inside the CSS folder? If so, remove the '..'.
Filenames might be case sensitive, verify that they are the same.

Comment: verified but it remains same

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background:#000 url('../img/dot.png' ) repeat 0 0;
```

If this doesn't work try to write out the full path or supply us with more code and give your path where the file is located.

Comment: What's your full path to the img? Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the website url.

Make sure the image is available in the same path on the server

Answer (score 0):

right click on background of ur website and check the path returned by Browser and let me know that path or simply inspect ur background with any tool like firebug or in internet explorer hitting F12, just inspect your Background to check what path is browser producing.

Comment: finally i got fixed it, bg image extensions in caps just changed into small.. Itz working now :)